# Error in restarting my mysql services using xampp in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, php, services, xampp

I installed xampp and for that period of time it worked but after i restarted my system the localhost was not running my php file
i tried:

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

but there is no mysql in /etc/init.d

Answer (score 0):

Try the new command

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: there is no mysql in /etc/init.d. 

Also `sudo service mysql restart` shows this error:
"Unit mysqld.service could not be found."